# Is the set of affiliated elements an algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a concrete $C^*$-algebra, i.e, embedded in $B(H)$, the set of all bounded operators on some Hilbert space $H$. In the sense of Woronowicz, a closed operator $a$ is said to be affiliated with $A$ if $z_a=a(1+a^*a)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is in $M(A)$, the multiplier algebra of $A$, and $(1+a^*a)^{-\frac{1}{2}}A$ is linearly dense in $A$. This affiliation relation is expressed as $a\eta A$. Define
$$
A^{\eta}:=\{a\mid a\eta A\}
$$

Is $A^{\eta}$ an algebra?

My intuition says that it is not.
It is known that if $a_1,a_2\eta A$ then $a_1+a_2\eta A$ but I'm not sure about the product  structure as the products of unbounded operators does not behave well. Any hint, direction or a counter example will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $A=B(H)$ I think every closed operator is affiliated to $A$, as $a(1+a^*a)^{-1/2}$ is always bounded. But the product of two closed operators does not need to be closed (neither does the sum!). I'm not sure if the product of two closed operators is however _closeable_.